# How to capture drop-down, checkbox and radio selected text?

Tags: c#, vb.net

This is a **hard** one. Need to read in plain text from Word, HTML files, and any readable content from drag-n-drop or copy-n-paste. See below for examples:

> - Drag-n-drop from Word or alike editor:

[image]

> - Copy-n-paste from browsers:

[image]

Using the suggested block I'm able to read in most text except the selected values of drop-down, checkbox and radio buttons.

```
var text = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText(); 
Clipboard.SetText(text);
```

How to capture the **missing selected values/text of drop-down, checkbox and radio button**?

Comment: You can use a simple `Textbox` instead of making a new Notepad.

Comment: There are already many Windows utilities that do this.

Comment: @DourHighArch can you name a few?

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText(); 
Clipboard.SetText(text);
```

Will turn the rich text on the clipboard into plain text.

On every machine I use I keep a batch file, calld `text.bat` on my `path` which does this to the clipboard contents, so I can press Win+R then type `text` and convert my clipboard contents to plain text.

Comment: Works great except still can't read drop-down, radio button and checkboxe.